# Getting executable file not found in $PATH: un known error message

Tags: docker, go, dockerfile

I'm getting executable file not found in $PATH: unknown error while trying to run docker image of golang project. Following is my docker file.

```
FROM golang:latest
LABEL maintainer = "Nisal Perera <xxx@sss.com>"
RUN mkdir -p /go/src/github.com/user/app/
COPY . /go/src/github.com/user/app/
WORKDIR /go/src/github.com/user/app/
RUN go get -u github.com/golang/dep/cmd/dep
#RUN dep init
RUN dep ensure
RUN go build
CMD ["go run main.go"]
```

The error I'm getting is the following

```
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:370: starting container process caused: exec: "go run main.go": executable file not found in $PATH: un
known.
```

Please help me with this. thanks

Comment: 1. Never, ever, EVER use `go run main.go`.  2. Your arguments to `CMD` need to be an array, not a single string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You dont need to use `go run ...` since you previously run `go build`, built file will be named after directory and looks like its `app`, try `CMD ["./app"]`

BTW the right usage of `CMD` in your case would be `CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]`, the error you have is related to `CMD` command its assume `go run main.go` is one file but it's not.

Answer (score 4):

You're trying to use the `CMD` clause in its *exec* [form](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd) so you have to split the command and its arguments. The accepted format is

```
CMD ["executable","param1","param2"]
```

So yours would be

```
CMD ["go", "run", "main.go"]
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting this error as the file "main.go" is not available at the working directory where it is executing the "go run main.go" command.

Please check the main.go file is available or not if yes then please define the complete path for the main.go file and try.